# setting a nested value in PStore

Tags: ruby

PStore is a data-serializer in the Stdlib which is human-readable like JSON or YAML.

Everything has to be done in a "transaction", e.g.

```
storage = PStore.new("db")

storage.transaction do |db|
  db[:key] = {}
  db[:key][:sub_key] = "val"
  return db[:key][:sub_key]
end
# ==> "val"
```

I want to be able to make a method like this:

```
def store(storage, list_of_keys, value)
  storage.transaction do |db|
    db[list_of_keys[0][list_of_keys[1]][list_of_keys[n]] = value
  end
end
```

Conceptually I think currying would be useful here, but I've only done it in Javascript.

It doesn't seem to work to store the references to the intermediate values in variables like this:

```
storage.transaction do |db|
  db_val_1 = db[keys[0]]
  db_val_1 = value
end
```

Comment: I sense that you need a recursive function here.

Comment: I don't think "currying" means what you think it means. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thank you but the answer you wrote doesn't work, its like the last example i gave. The `current_db` variable in your example doesn't actually refer to the db anymore.

Comment: If this works `db[:key][:sub_key] = "val"`, then that code should have worked too. Anyhow, I didn't work with PStore, so it must be having its quirks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you want. But my guess is you wanna store a value inside a nested hash with given list of keys. Since it's a nested has, I would use, well, a hash obviously. Here is a full working code for what I think you are trying to do:

```
require 'pstore'
require 'minitest/autorun'


storage = PStore.new("data_file.pstore")

def nest(key_list, value)
  reverse_key_list = key_list.reverse
  inner_most = {"#{reverse_key_list.shift}" => value}
  reverse_key_list.reduce(inner_most) {|acc, current| {"#{current}" => acc }}
end

def nested_store(storage, key_list, value)
  root = key_list.shift
  data = nest(key_list, value)
  storage.transaction { storage[root] = data }
end 

describe "pstore test" do
  before do
    @key_list = %w(root sub1 sub2 sub3)
    @val = "value"
  end

  it "should nest the list" do
    nest(@key_list, @val).must_equal({"root" => {"sub1" => {"sub2" => {"sub3" => "value" }}}})
  end

  it "store the nested list" do
    storage = PStore.new("data_file.pstore")
    nested_store(storage, @key_list, @val)
    storage.transaction do          
      storage["root"]["sub1"]["sub2"]["sub3"].must_equal "value"
    end
  end
end
```